# Uneven lighting in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

I'm making a new animation and for some reason, the lighting in the render isn't even.

I've tried adding an area light but no matter how bright it is, the dark faces on the right don't show any change.

It's all indirect lighting and with the symmetry, I want both sides would be lit the same way.

Here's a frame that shows what I'm talking about. (Surrounding the coin-op on the right hand side, it's all dark) [image: uneven lighting]

Any help is appreciated. I'm a bit stumped.

Edit: I've also noticed some splotches of darkness above the coin-op on the left. Could it be the texture?

Second edit: Link to file coming soon. Clamping and environment lighting did basically nothing.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mguxyLO8M8u8hAYRC3nFBJzHZht4XHMB/view?usp=drivesdk

Sorry it took so long to get my file uploaded! Hope this helps!

Comment: It is hard to tell without more information. Are you clamping any of the rays? Please show the render settings for light paths. Also consider uploading your file so others can inspect it and help you.

Comment: I'm not sure what clamping rays means, so probably not.  I'll update the post with a link to the file here in a little bit too! Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: If you want even lighting you can try to enable the Environment lighting.

Comment: Updated the post. Tried clamping and turning on environment lighting but nothing changed.

Comment: try changing the color management to filmic blender , and also have a look at the false color

Comment: Have you noticed that there is two overlapped objects on the right part? For the other aspects, I have not understood what should be symmetrical here about light? Both side do not have the same materials, it seems... ?

Comment: Oh my word, you're absolutely right. I have no idea how I missed that.  Also, about the lighting. The materials were made and then the object was copied over to the other side so the materials are the same.

Comment: Well, it seems that 3 cubes cube cube.001 and cube.002 have different materials each other. Which is the one to delete?

Comment: Took a look and Cube is the one to delete. Was unsure how the yellow glossy texture on the left was changed, but it's changed back. Now they should be the same.

Comment: The sequence is long... at which frame the issue occurs?

Comment: The whole way down the lighting is buggy on the right.

Comment: There are several differences. Check face orientations. There are inverted but not on the same parts in left and right. Also cube.001 has a material.001 which is not used forcube.002...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference in lightning does **Material 2** - **Magic texture**.
This node generates black material on some faces differently, depence on object position.

On the left side are black back sides of object on the right sides are black front sides of objects.

Disabling node from node tree fix the lightning issue.

[image]

Node attached into Normal socket generates blacks on all negative XYZ axis directions.

[image]

I don't know what is a proper way, but ussally you should plug node into Color socket. So try this.

[image]

*Plus as already mentioned - you have overlaping objects with different materials. But even I kept only one side and Mirrored with modifier, issue was there.*

Comment: That's helped the lighting but lost me the texture I was going for. Then the mirror modifier is flipping the text at the top of the cabinet.

Comment: Solution for that was duplicating, flipping 180, and then placing it in the right spot.

Comment: @Vanessa Can use another array modifier to mirror a part to the other side. Use object offset option

Comment: It's not exactly where I want this visually but your answer got me the closest to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Updated to some tip. You would need probably Texture Coordinates node and Mapping node as well.

Answer (score -1):

Please Check your Materials. I guess you might have no specular with black base color in you Principled Bsdf node OR by accident you might have attached Black Emission in your shader output.

Comment: That was one of the first things I checked when troubleshooting and my materials all seem to be set right in material view. It's only when I switch to rendered that it turns black.